# Enter The Market

Tags: word-meaning

I have some question about the usage of the verb "*enter*":

> 1. New companies *entered* the market.
> 2. New products *entered* the market.

According to definition 2 from this [dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enter) for "*enter*":

> def 2: to start to take part in a particular activity or to work in a particular job

with the example usage sentence:

> There are dozens of new companies ***entering*** the software market.

which suggests that sentence 1 is correct and sentence 2 is wrong.

But then, according to definition 3c from another [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/enter) for "*enter*":

> def 3c: to appear for the first time in (something)

with this example usage sentence:

> The company has several new products now ***entering*** the marketplace.

which suggests that sentence 1 is wrong and sentence 2 is the correct usage.  What do native speakers think?  Is either 1 or 2 wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong grammatically with any of the sentences presented by the OP.  The verb enter is used in many senses. The OP has described only two meanings of this verb. There are a lot of its uses. The most important and common meaning of the vetb is "to go into a room, building, or other place", which is quite different from the meanings mentioned by the OP.  We cannot say that only one meaning is correct and the others are incorrect.

Comment: So, the two sentences are technical lingo, considered standard English in their respective fields?

Comment: Yes, it's standard English.

Comment: But the two sentences may be nonstandard in regular non-technical English?